# How to Extend a Helper in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add some new functions to the core `string` helper, which is found in `system/helpers` folder. I think there was a 'right' way to do this using `MY_String_helper`, or something of that sort. I can't remember exactly how it was done though. Any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found it. Make a file with a name such as this, in the `application/helpers` directory:

```
MY_xx_helper.php
```

E.g:

```
MY_string_helper.php
```

Then you can call

```
$this->load->helper('string');
```

And it should load all the existing helper functions as well as the new ones you add.

Answer (score 8):

Doing that you can not only add new functions but replace exising helper functions.

Answer (score 1):

For a primary source, in case things change in the future, the [CodeIgniter User Guide's Helpers page](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) has a section describing how to extend helpers.

Comment: It's ironic that the link you added for posterity became invalid sooner than the direct answer you were concerned with

Comment: Yes! Updated the link in my answer finally, hopefully it won't become invalid so quickly again.